# How to make cropping in video on mousemove

Tags: javascript, html

I am cropping image with required area,which demo you can see at'http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/197/index.html' but i want to use video in place of image,how to do it ? I had tried lot using following code but nothing happened.Can anybody help?

```
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>html5 : how to crop a video tag into a canvas tag</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function onLoadEvent() {
function loop(){
 var video = document.getElementById('video');
 ctx.drawImage(video, 320, 0, 320, 180, 0, 0, 640, 360);
 setTimeout(loop, 1000 / 30);
 }
var canvas = document.getElementById('cropCvs');
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
loop();
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="javascript:onLoadEvent()">
 <video
 id="video"
 height="360"
 width="640"
 autoplay
 controls
 src="http://cdn.kaltura.org/apis/html5lib/kplayer-examples/media/bbb_trailer_360p.webm?a"
 style="width: 640px; height: 360px; border: 1px solid black;">
 </video>
 <canvas
 id="cropCvs"
 height="360"
 width="640"
 style="width: 320px; height: 180px; border: 1px solid black;">
 </canvas>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: When you say that nothing happened, what do you mean? No cropping? No errors?

Comment: In place of image as in demo it displays blank.

Comment: And if you launch the console? Is anything outputted?

Comment: Have you tried just loading the video? If I load http://cdn.kaltura.org/apis/html5lib/kplayer-examples/media/bbb_trailer_360p.webm?a in a browser, it redirects to a directory page. Looks like the demo's link has broken.